# Criar um elipse / circulo em unity + C# - utilizando Point3D e VirtualDraw

Tags: c#, unity3d

Preciso implementar em um projeto Unity, a criação de um elipse. No projeto já existe o código de criação de "linha" e "retângulo" que funciona perfeitamente. O projeto é para um mestrado e professor já disponibilizou um "esqueleto" do código. Sendo assim a parte do código do circulo, está com o código que cria a linha.

Código que cria o retângulo:

```
private void draw(double x, double y, double z) //criar retangulo
{
  string text;

  if (m_pts.Count != 1)
    return;

  if (m_pDrawObj == null)
    return;

  // obtain initial and final point in local coordenate system
  Point3D p00 = m_plane.uvPoint(m_pts[0]);
  Point3D p11 = m_plane.uvPoint(new Point3D(x,y,z));

  // obtain other corner points
  Point3D p01 = m_plane.eval(p00.getX(), p11.getY());
  Point3D p10 = m_plane.eval(p11.getX(), p00.getY());

  m_pDrawObj.Line(m_pts[0].getX(), m_pts[0].getY(), m_pts[0].getZ(), p01.getX(), p01.getY(), p01.getZ());
  m_pDrawObj.Line(p01.getX(), p01.getY(), p01.getZ(), x, y, z);
  m_pDrawObj.Line(m_pts[0].getX(), m_pts[0].getY(), m_pts[0].getZ(), p10.getX(), p10.getY(), p10.getZ());
  m_pDrawObj.Line(p10.getX(), p10.getY(), p10.getZ(), x, y, z);

  // draw text update length
  Point3D pt = new Point3D(x, y, z);
  text = "Rectangle = " + m_pts[0].distance(pt).ToString();

  Point3D c = (m_pts[0] + pt) / 2.0;
  m_pDrawObj.text(c.getX(), c.getY(), c.getZ(), text);

}
```

Código do circulo:

```
private void draw(double x, double y, double z) //criar circulo
    {
        string text;

        if (m_pts.Count != 1)
            return;

        if (m_pDrawObj == null)
            return;

        m_pDrawObj.Line(m_pts[0].getX(), m_pts[0].getY(), m_pts[0].getZ(), x, y, z);

        // draw text update length
        Point3D pt = new Point3D(x, y, z);

        text = "Line = " + m_pts[0].distance(pt).ToString();

        Point3D c = (m_pts[0] + pt) / 2.0;

        m_pDrawObj.text(c.getX(), c.getY(), c.getZ(), text);

    }
```

Se possível gostaria que fosse indicado como consigo criar um circulo neste projeto, já utilizando essa classe point3D e o VirtualDraw.Line. Já fiz varias pesquisas mas não consegui achar nada parecido com o código que já existe

[image]

Aqui é possível ver o projeto executando, basicamente é clicar na figura circulo na parte de cima e clicar e arrastar no plano e montar o circulo

Qualquer ajuda será bem vinda! Obrigado.

Comment: Eu só vi sua pergunta hoje, mas mesmo assim até o momento ela não teve nenhuma resposta ou sequer um comentário. A razão: é muito difícil te ajudar, porque o seu código é difícil de compreender. Pegue o desenho do retângulo, por exemplo. A função recebe uma única coordenada 3D! O desenho em si parece usar estruturas que externas (um tal de `m_pts`, por exemplo). Por mais que alguém pudesse dar uma resposta tangencial, o fato da sua pergunta estar difícil desestimula a isso.

Comment: A minha sugestão então é: crie um [mcve] que reproduza o que você já tem e a sua dificuldade, e disponibilize para que alguém possa baixar, testar e te ajudar de forma pragmática. :)